# How to prevent accidentally deletion of spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

I am using google drive sheets every day and today i deleted a folder by mistake so please share me the ways how to prevent the sheet deleting it

Answer (score 0):

In Google Drive, deleted files actually are moved to Trash. You can move back to My Drive from there.

In order to prevent accidentally "deletions" you could use another account to be used only as the owner of your spreadsheets.